# Problem with guessing game, player has infinite guesses

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to build a guessing game in Python. You have a limited number of around 5 guesses/lives and if you run out of them, you will lose the game. (for reference: it uses both `random`(for random number) and `termcolor`(for color) modules)

Program:

```
from termcolor import colored
import random

def lostit():
    print(colored("Sorry! You lost!", "red"))
    decideto = input("Try again? (yes/no):")
    while decideto not in ("yes", "no"):
        decideto = input(colored("Invalid response:", "red"))
    if decideto is "yes":
        guessnum()
    elif decideto is "no":
        print("Bye, bye.")


def guessnum():
     numtoguess = random.randint(1, 10)
     print(colored("I've picked a random number from 0 to 9! Guess what it is! You've got 3 hints and 5 guesses!", "green"))
     usernum = input(colored("Try to guess it: ", "cyan"))
     guesses = 5 # The limit
     usertries = 0 # Chances
     if guesses >= usertries:
         while usernum != numtoguess:
             usernum = input(colored("Wrong! Guess again: ", "red"))
             usertries += 1 # Tried to make it add until the limit, but doesn't work
     elif guesses == usertries:
         lostit()
     print(colored("Great job! You guessed it!", "green"))
```

So far, it works when you type in the right number. However, I've experienced problems with the lives/guesses part. I've tried to set a limit to how many tries the player has, however the program seems to ignore this, meaning the player basically has infinite lives. How do I solve this?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. I'd suggest using triple backticks ``` on their own line instead of the trailing spaces on each line, so that you can copy-paste what you have.

Comment: Note the difference of global and local variables. I think that is the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(colored("Sorry! You lost!", "red"))
decideto = input("Try again? (yes/no):")
```

should likely be indented.

This is also strange. You don't have a variable called lostit, but you have a loop with that variable:

```
while lostit not in ("yes", "no"):
```

The logic on your code is simply wrong. See this loop:

```
 while usernum != numtoguess:
            usernum = input(colored("Wrong! Guess again: ", "red"))
            usertries += 1 # Tried to make it add until the limit, but doesn't work
```

You are looping while the guess isn't equal to number you selected.

I would reorg. Main function defines the number to guess, how many guesses they get, it loops while two things are true (guess isn't equal to number and guess count is less than total number of guesses). Also note the scope of variables.

```
from termcolor import colored
import random

def guessnum():
    numtoguess = random.randint(1, 10)
    print(colored("I've picked a random number from 0 to 9! Guess what it is! You've got 3 hints and 5 guesses!", "green"))
    usernum = input(colored("Try to guess it: ", "cyan"))
    guesses = 5 # The limit
    usertries = 1 # Chances, but they already used a guess
    while (usernum != numtoguess) and (guesses >= usertries):
        again = input("Try again? (yes/no):")
        while again not in ("yes", "no"):
            again = input(colored("Invalid response choose yes/no:", "red"))
        if decideto is "yes":
            usernum = input(colored("Wrong! Guess again: ", "red"))
            usertries += 1
        elif decideto is "no":
            print("Bye, bye.")
            return
    if usernum == numtoguess:
        print(colored("Great job! You guessed it!", "green"))
    if guesses >= usertries:
        print(colored("Sorry! You lost!", "red"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this section:

```py
if guesses >= usertries:
    while usernum != numtoguess:
        usernum = input(colored("Wrong! Guess again: ", "red"))
        usertries += 1 # Tried to make it add until the limit, but doesn't work
elif guesses == usertries:
    lostit()
```

First of all, your if and elif are not mutually exclusive: let's say `guesses` is equal to `usertries`. It will enter to first if (since you use >=) and not the second elif (because it entered the first one). In other words, Elif code is not reachable.

Seoncd, your while loop is inside the if. It keeps running until you guess the right number, and only then compare your guess with "lives". You should substitute the statements to check the lives inside the loop:

```py
while guesses >= usertries:
    usernum = input(colored("Wrong! Guess again: ", "red"))
    if usernum != numtoguess:
        usertries += 1
        # User is wrong. We add one to our counter
    else
       # user is right. Do something to break the loop

# When we reach here, we ended loop: means user lost
lostit()
```

The logic is: as long as user has guesses, ask him for another number. compare the number: if he is right, do something. else, keep loop.